# EclipseLink - Query failed to prepare, unexpected error occurred

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, eclipselink

When executing a command, EntityManager throws out(all https://pastebin.com/zKYBhsv8)

```
[EL Warning]: 2017-10-14 20:07:55.332--UnitOfWork(402037615)--Exception [EclipseLink-6168] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Query failed to prepare, unexpected error occurred: [java.lang.NullPointerException].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=MovieEntity )
```

The code looks like this

I create

```
final CriteriaBuilder cb = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
final Root<MovieEntity> root = countQuery.from(MovieEntity.class);
```

then I create predicate

```
final Predicate whereClause = MovieSpecs
            .getFindPredicate(root, cb, countries);
```

this is the method

```
public static Predicate getFindPredicate(
        final Root<MovieEntity> root,
        final CriteriaBuilder cb
        final List<CountryType> countries
) {
    final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    if(countries != null && !countries.isEmpty()) {
        final List<Predicate> orPredicates =
                countries
                        .stream()
                        .map(status -> cb.equal(root.get(MovieEntity_.countries), countries))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        predicates.add(cb.or(orPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[orPredicates.size()])));
    }
    return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
}
```

then set predicate in countQuery

```
countQuery.select(cb.count(root)).where(whereClause);
```

and execute the command

```
final Long count = this.entityManager.createQuery(countQuery).getSingleResult();
```

and here I am throwing the above errors.

MovieEntity: https://pastebin.com/CvhEQFZD MovieEntity_: http s://pastebin.com/ZyJL0nmM

Comment: can you elaborate what you actually want to compare with this `cb.equal(root.get(MovieEntity_.countries), countries)` ?

Comment: Now I thought and saw that it was pointless. With this code, I wanted to check if the given country is on the list of film countries. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Use 'in' to check if an element is in the list, but you will need to be more specific, as a movie playing in two countries on the list will show up twice in your results due to the join over the OneToMany relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue occurs when EclipseLink is trying to process `countries` matching done against collection:

```
.map(status -> cb.equal(root.get(MovieEntity_.countries), *countries*))
```

I think your intent was to check for equality with streamed item

```
.map(status -> cb.equal(root.get(MovieEntity_.countries), status))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not help. You could have taken a look at it service https://pastebin.com/4tY5djAD and getFindPredicate https://pastebin.com/4eQb6yUE

Comment: Can you add ORM mapping for `MovieEntity` to the question?

Comment: I was editing. The best thing is that the error is only at the lists. There is no problem with individual objects.

Comment: This may sound as magic but try the next one: instead of building criteria comparing collection to object compare `MovieEntity.countries.id` to `country.id`. I have seen issues earlier with such queries when relation  foreign key was on collection item.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want all `MovieEntities` that have one or more of the provided `Countries` you could try to replace `cb.equal(root.get(MovieEntity_.countries), countries)` with `cb.isMember(status, MovieEntity_.countries)`.

However this might not be the most optimal way to do this but at least easiest to test against your current code. Maybe you should also change `status` to `country` to make code more understandable.