# Gets from the database with Spring Data according to specification

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I have a method that creates the specification

```
 public static Specification<MovieEntity> getFindPredicate(
        final String title
) {
    return (final Root<MovieEntity> root, final CriteriaQuery<?> cq, final CriteriaBuilder cb) -> {
        final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(title)) {
            final Join<MovieEntity, MovieTitle> title_ = root.join(MovieEntity_.title);
            predicates.add(cb.like(title_.get(MovieTitle_.title), "%" + title + "%"));
        }

      return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
   };

}
```

This specification shall be sent to the JPA repository

```
final Page<MovieEntity> movieEntities = this.movieRepository.findAll(
            MovieSpecs.getFindPredicate(
                    title),
            page);
```

And this is where strange things begin to happen.  If there is an object with a specific title in the database, it returns objects in the amount specified on the page object. So if I have entered a page with page size 10, and there is at least one object with the specified title in the database, then the JPA method will return 10 identical objects to me.

For example, I show it to myself.

I give the title `jonki1`. In the database I have only one object with the name of `jonki1`.

Code:

```
for (Iterator<MovieEntity> it = movieEntities.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        MovieEntity entity = it.next();
        System.out.println(entity.getTitle().getTitle());
    }
```

returns me

```
jonki1
jonki1
jonki1
jonki1
jonki1
jonki1
jonki1
jonki1
jonki1
jonki1
```

10 objects, because the `page` size is 10, but the object in the database is only one. Why is this happening?

Comment: Check how MoviewEntity and MovieTitle are related. Could be there is no proper relation (OneToOne I expect) or it is incorrectly defined. Post the entities definitions as well.

Comment: Turn on SQL logging to see the SQL that gets generated - it'll make it a bit easier to see what JPA is executing on the database and show how joins result in multiple results being returned.   From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46748527/eclipselink-query-failed-to-prepare-unexpected-error-occurred your find predicate is joining across a list, which will cause it to return N rows for each entities. You can simplify your queries to avoid unnecessary and costly joins, and/or use the Distinct option on your select to filter duplicate entities